# Insert null fails with Model First EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm using a context generated from an EDMX for a mvc3 webapp. I'm getting a NULL insert fails error on an entity

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[EdmEntityType(NamespaceName = "Model", Name = "Thing")]
public class Thing: EntityObject
{
    public RolloverEntry();

    [DataMember]
    [EdmScalarProperty(EntityKeyProperty = true, IsNullable = false)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [SoapIgnore]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationProperty("Model", "FK_ThingStep1", "Step1")]
    [DataMember]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public EntityCollection<Step1> Step1 { get; set; }
    [SoapIgnore]
    [EdmRelationshipNavigationProperty("Model", "FK_ThingStep2", "Step2")]
    [XmlIgnore]
    [DataMember]
    public EntityCollection<Step2> Step2 { get; set; }

    public static Thing CreateThing(int id);
}
```

Data access to other parent-child relationships are working and persisted correctly - I can't seem to find what's wrong with this table tho - any ideas appreciated

Exception Recieved:

{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'myapp.dbo.Thing'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Thanks

Comment: can you show the Message / Stack Trace for the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you need some sort of hint in your model that the database should generate the ids for the id column.  You might want to see if `StoreGeneratedPattern` is set to `Identity` for your model property `id` or something along those lines.